# Salesforce automatically converts amount value when process builder updates currencyIsoCode

Tags: process-builder

Posting this here for reference as I have never seen this documented.  If anyone has seen this documented or has more insight into this functionality, I would like to understand it.

If process builder changes `currencyIsoCode` on a record, salesforce will automatically convert any currency fields (ie amount) on the record to the value in the new `currencyIsoCode` from the prior value of `currencyIsoCode`

So, for example

1. User enters 10 in `amount__c`,(type = currency)
2. Set currency on record to CAD
3. Process builder updates currencyIsoCode to INR on save
4. Amount is updated 517.86 on save

So there are two conversions happening

1. 10 CAD -> 7.93 USD
2. 7.93 USD -> 517.86 INR

There is nothing else operating on this object - its a vanilla custom object with only this one record update process node that sets currencyIsoCode to INR.

The final amount varies based on the value of `currencyIsoCode` entered on the record.  So Salesforce is assuming that the value is entered in the currency entered, and then automatically converts to the new currency.

Screenshots below.  If anyone has documentation that supports this behavior, please share.

Before
[image: record before save]

After
[image: record after save]

Lightning Process
[image: process record update node]

Comment: if you go to DevConsole and simply do a DML update of CurrencyIsoCode (from CAD to INR) of a Currency Field with value `10`, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only docu [I found ist the one about Multi-Currency.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_currency.htm&type=5)

> When you change the default currency of a record, currency amounts are not converted. They display the new currency code.

In fact what this documentation says is only true depending on the way the change is done!
If the update also specifies the amount, the amount is not changed. (This is the case for a normal edit over the layout)

Example: 100 USD --> 100 EUR (The user only changes the Opportunity Currency from USD to EUR, but the Amount is on the layout and therefore contained in the update)

However, when the update does not explicitly contain the Amount field, the amount will be adapted. There are two ways to try this. Dataloader or "Execute Anonymous" via Dev Console. For the latter just type

```
update new Opportunity(Id = '*18digit ID of an Opportunity with USD Currency*', CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR');
```

The amount will change accordingly.

```
update new Opportunity(Id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR', Amount = 100);
```

won't adapt the Amount.

So if you include the Amount from the record in your update, only the CurrencyIsoCode will be adapted.

I was not able to find even a shred of documentation to support this.

Comment: Nicely done!  That is fascinating.  And bizarre!

Comment: One of those things where SF thinks for you, if you want it or not. Unaccaptable is, that the documentation is uncomplete, and in many cases just wrong. It says there was no automatism, but under certain conditions there is...At least now we know those conditions and get our beloved deterministic behaviour back. :D